# The Gaming Blog needs the Arqade treatment too

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog, arqade-migration

<sup>(Yes I'm done with lame question bodies. <sub>For today. <sup>It feels like Christmas or something. <sub>Reading such thiny print hurts your eyes!</sub></sup></sub>)</sup>

As Jin is aware, [our blog](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/) no longer matches our website's style. This meta post is made merely to give Jin (or Jin-alikes) the satisfaction to mark this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) once the necessary tweaks are published.

Comment: I shall have that satisfaction this week. stay tuned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a placeholder answer that calls attention to the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag in hopes that this answer gets accepted or up-voted so that Community♦ (that wily rascal) doesn't keep bumping this back to the front page every few weeks until the [Eschaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eschaton).*